# Blocked mirror for repositories: [centralhttp (http://....maven.org/maven2/, default, releases+snapshots)]

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I've generated files from WSDL, and right now I've it on my remote repository.

Now if I have added dependencies to my project poms and reload maven I have errors like this

[Blocked mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OBI9.png)

Or if I run mvn -U clean install i get error like below:
Could not find artifact ....webservices:pom:1.0.0

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Using http instead of https....upgrading Maven etc....

Comment: Start with upgrading to newest version of Maven.